# New installation can't be found due to htaccess of the original non-Wordpress site

Tags: htaccess

I have a non-Wordpress site , **www.example.com**

For canonicalization purposes I have this in .htaccess :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This way all non-www links will be redirected to www version of site.

Recently I decided to attach a wordpress blog at **www.example.com/blog** . After the installation is complete, whenever I go to **www.example.com/blog** I get 404 - Page not found error. I tried both auto install with Fantastico and a manual install, with the same result.

I found out that when I remove the piece of code above from my .htaccess it fixes the problem, and wordpress installation is accessable and usable.

However, I would like to keep the the original htaccess settings, for SEO purposes. I tried to change url version in wordpress General Settings and then restore main site htaccess file - it would still break the wordpress and 404 is back again.

I tried to add next code in wp-config.php :

```
define('WP_HOME','http://www.example.com/blog');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.example.com/blog');
```

It didn't fixed the problem either...

I understand it has something to do with htaccess. I also notices that there is no htaccess file in wordpress folder, probably due to the fact that I haven't changed permalinks settings yet.

I would appreciate any help on this matter!

P.S: I just noticed that **www.example.com/blog/wp-login.php** is visible regardless of htaccess config, however after I log in it brings me to 404 page again :(

Comment: home and site url should be `http://www.example.com/blog` if it's installed in a folder named `blog`.

Comment: yeah it is blog, sorry I submited the code from the example webpage, let me update original post

Comment: what is the url it sends you to when you log in? make sure you clear your cache after any change, your browser *will* cache a 404 page. I tried your .htaccess rules on my own server and wp in a directory and it all works fine, not sure what your issue is.

Comment: When I log in it sends me to **www.example.com/blog/wp-admin/** ... I also been clearing cache every step of the way .. I know this wierd and htaccess rules work fine for non-wordpress part of site, it just for some reason the wordpress is having issues with it :(

Comment: Try going to http://example.com/blog/wp-admin/options-permalink.php.  That should work, because the php file actually exists.  If so, try updating your permalink options to a friendly version, like "Day and name".  This will put a new `.htaccess` in the `blog` directory -- I'm thinking that that new .htaccess will override the one in the parent directory.

Comment: @Chris Carson  - you are my friend is a genius! It solved the problem :))))

Comment: @Chris Carson - you should add your solution as an answer.

Comment: Alex and @Milo - Thanks!  Added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per @Milo, I'm adding my comment above as an answer...

Try going to `example.com/blog/wp-admin/options-permalink.php`. That should work, because the php file actually exists. If so, try updating your permalink options to a friendly version, like "Day and name". This will put a new `.htaccess` in the blog directory -- I'm thinking that that new `.htaccess` will override the one in the parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that code. WordPress itself handles redirects to canonical URLs. Just set it up to have the www address in Settings->General and it will redirect the traffic without your htaccess rules.

Comment: I know about this wordpress ability, but My main site is non-Wordpress, wordpress is just a little blog in a blog folder...